# how do i rewrite www.domain.com to another domain's /www/domain.com/index.php?

Tags: mod-rewrite

i have this on my htaccess currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule (.*) /www/$1/index.php
```

but i keep getting an error page

what im trying to do is to register a lot of domains for clients 
and just store all their websites' files on a folder named "theirdomain.com" on my domain's www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will never find www in the URI BEcause the URI is everything after index.php? so the uri will be index.php?**/here/is/the.uri/string**

I would look at HTTP_HOST

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^first-host.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-host.com/$1 [L,R=301] #Send 301 so search engines know where to go.
</IfModule>
```

Comment: im not sure i understand you. the query string follows the ?  in a list of params. foo=bar&bar=foo

Comment: so for example the domain this htaccess is on www.mydomain.com .
We have someone we register as someone.com and forward their dns to www.mydomain.com,
now htaccess should point to the mydomain.com/www/someone.com/index.php

is that possible?

Comment: I very much doubt this is possible via htaccess, you need to set up your DNS records on your server to point to a perticular user, so theredomain.com will point to /server/domains/theredomain.com/public_html/ im not the best at server and dns but i belive a method like this is what's needed